# Regex: Excluding certain characters unless it is between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I exclude certain characters from the search unless they are between quotes.

example:

characters to exclude: `[%#0;]`

text not match:

```
pref%xxx
suff#xx
someRandomTxt0ddf
```

text that matches:

```
pref'%'xxx
suff'#'xx
someRandomText'0'ddf
```

Comment: what do you mean by `exclude from the search`

Comment: What about `pref'%xxx` or `pref%'xxx` (just only one quote) must they match or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
^(?!.*(?:(?<!')[%#0;](?!')|(?<=')[%#0;](?!')|(?<!')[%#0;](?='))).*$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
^              from the start of the input
    (?!.*(?:   assert that we cannot look forward and find any of the three following
        (?<!') any non single quote character
        [%#0;] followed any one of these characters
        (?!')  followed again by any non single quote character
        |      OR
        (?<=') a single quote
        [%#0;] followed any one of these characters
        (?!')  followed again by any non single quote character
        |      OR
        (?<!') any non single quote character
        [%#0;] followed any one of these characters
        (?!')  followed by a single quote
    ))
    .*         then match any other content without restriction
$              end of the input
```

Comment: Nice one. Just a remarck lookbehind is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @Toto Would love to see your attempt at this question...I'll bet you can shorten my answer a bit `:-)`

Comment: May be [this](https://regex101.com/r/f2JO7X/3) but it rejects `abc'%def` (only one quote) I don't know if it has to be accepted or not..

Comment: Great, you should post it, can't believe I didn't think of this.  Your interpretation is correct, two single quotes are needed for an escape, just one is not sufficient.

Comment: Just waiting OP for clarification, but I will not answer, I've just simplified your regex. Feel free to add it to your answer when OP will clarify ;)

Comment: Plus one for the regex-only solution. In my opinion, it would be better to use a simpler expression with some programming logic though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with a simple solution like below?

```
/'[%#0;]'/
```

https://regex101.com/r/T3lQRO/1

Comment: I think you should (re)read the question!

Comment: The question is worded poorly. Either this answer is correct or it's the exact opposite of what was asked, depending on what the asker really meant.

Comment: This matches inputs which _don't_ have any problems...it does not match offending inputs, nor does it match any other valid inputs which don't have any escaped characters.

Comment: The problem is to select the match if it does not contain the excluded chars or if it has one or more of the excluded chars but escaped with quotes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simpler regex and some programming logic:

```
('[^']+')|[%#0;]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pH0g1L/1).

---

In `JavaScript` this could be:

```js
let strings = ["pref%xxx", "suff#xx", "someRandomTxt0ddf", "pref'%'xxx", "suff'#'xx", "someRandomText'0'ddf"];

let pattern = /('[^']+')|[%#0;]/g;

strings.forEach(function(string) {
    cnt = 0;
    match = pattern.exec(string);
    while (match != null) {
        if (typeof(match[1]) == "undefined") cnt += 1;
        match = pattern.exec(string);
    }
    if (cnt == 0)
        console.log(string);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
^([^%#0;]|(?<=')[%#0;](?='))*$
```

1. `^` Matches start of string
2. `[^%#0;]` First alternate: Match any character that isn't one of '%#0;'
3. `(?<=')[%#0;]` Second alternate: Match one of '%#0;` only if preceded and followed by quotes
4. `*`: Repeat 0 or more times. (change to + to ensure at least one character in match).
5. `$` Matches end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5nIG9/1/)